# PyTorch autograd second derivative not working (?)

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch, derivative, autograd

I have been trying to get PyTorch to output the correct second derivative of a function.  The `MC_basket` function calculates the value of an option contract.  Delta, the first derivative with respect to `F0`, works correctly.  Gamma, the second derivative with respect to `F0`, I can't tell if I implemented it correctly.  Seems odd since I call autograd on the sum of the first derivative.

Can anyone who is experienced in PyTorch autograd look at how I have calculated Gamma, and let me know if it is correct?  In the Greeks function below:

```
import torch
import numpy as np


def MC_basket(F0, vols, K, T, IR, corr, weights, trials):
    torch.manual_seed(123)
    eigvals, eigvects = torch.linalg.eigh(corr)
    eigvals[eigvals < 0.00001] = 0.00001
    V = torch.real(torch.mm(eigvects, torch.sqrt(torch.diag(eigvals))))
    randnums = torch.randn(F0.shape[0], trials).double() #2D Euro
    randnumscorr = torch.matmul(V.double(), randnums).T   
    paths = F0 *torch.exp((-0.5*vols*vols)*T + randnumscorr*vols*torch.sqrt(T))
    # smooth the function for 2nd derivative (gamma)
    payoff = torch.sum(paths*weights, axis=1)-K
    payoff = HeavisideApprox(payoff)* payoff
    return torch.mean(payoff)* torch.exp(-IR*T)

def Greeks(F0, vols, K, T, IR, corr, weights, trials):
    # run pytorch first to get gradient functions
    NPV = MC_basket(F0, vols, K, T, IR, corr, weights, trials)
    # solve for Greeks and standardize outputs
    delta = torch.autograd.grad(NPV, F0, create_graph=True, retain_graph=True)[0]
    gamma = weights*torch.autograd.grad(delta.sum(), F0)[0]
    return NPV, delta, gamma

def HeavisideApprox(x):
    return 0.5 + 0.5 * torch.tanh(100*x)

F0 = torch.tensor([120.0,80.0], requires_grad=True)
vols = torch.tensor([0.8,0.7])
K = torch.tensor(100.0)
T = torch.tensor(0.1)
IR = torch.tensor(0.03)
corr = torch.tensor([[1, 0.9],[0.9,1]])
weights = torch.tensor([0.4, 0.6])
trials = 1000000

NPV, delta, gamma = Greeks(F0, vols, K, T, IR, corr, weights, trials)
print("\nMC basket price:", round(NPV.item(),3), "\ndelta:", np.round(delta.detach().numpy(), 3), "\ngamma:", np.round(gamma.detach().numpy(),3))

# calculate Finite Differences delta and gamma for comparison with AAD
gammaFD = torch.zeros((len(F0),))
deltaFD = torch.zeros((len(F0),))
bump = 0.005

for i in range(0,F0.shape[0]):
    MCb_up = torch.zeros((len(F0),))
    MCb_down = torch.zeros((len(F0),))
    MCb_up[i] = bump
    MCb_down[i] = -bump
    MCb_up[i] = MC_basket(F0+MCb_up, vols, K, T, IR, corr, weights, trials)
    MCb_down[i] = MC_basket(F0+MCb_down, vols, K, T, IR, corr, weights, trials)
    gammaFD[i] = (MCb_up[i] - 2*NPV + MCb_down[i]) / bump**2
    deltaFD[i] = (MCb_up[i] - MCb_down[i]) / (2*bump)

print("\ndeltas FD:",np.round(deltaFD.detach().numpy(),3))
print("\ngammas FD:", np.round(gammaFD.detach().numpy(),3))
```

Output:

```
MC basket price: 7.143 
delta: [0.192 0.281] 
gamma: [0.003 0.007]

deltas FD: [0.192 0.28 ]
gammas FD: [0.001 0.02 ]
```